# How do I refresh Fragment after Activity is created using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

I want to create things at runtime and I have global variable in my FragmentActivity that I want to set and they are then used by the Fragments in the onActivityCreated() method. But obviously they are null when they are created and it isn't until after the Fragment is created that I need to use the data. Has anyone worked out a good way of doing this? I am currently using ActionBarSherlock to do this.

I want to be able to refresh the Fragment, but not the Activity as then everything will be null again.

Please can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

FragmentActivity code:

```
public class SlidingTabsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{   

/* Sliding tabs */
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBarTabs;

/* Custom tab view */
private LayoutInflater customTabViewLayoutInflater;
private View customTabView;

/* Layer interfaces */
private CommsLayerInterface commsLayerInterface;
private DeviceLayerInterface deviceLayerInterface;

private PopupFirmware popupFirmware; // Popup firmware class instance

/* Data set information */
private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
private Pages pages;
private Page page1;
private Page page2;
private Page page3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(viewPager);

    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager); // Declares the tabs adapter class with the view pager view

    popupFirmware = new PopupFirmware(this); // Declaring popup firmware class

    commsLayerInterface = new CommsLayerInterface();
    deviceLayerInterface = new DeviceLayerInterface(this);

    deviceLayerInterface.setCommsLayerInterface(commsLayerInterface);

    /* Custom tab view instances */
    customTabViewLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    customTabView = customTabViewLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_spinner, null);

    /* Custom view functions */
    TabCustomViewFunctions.createSpinnerList(this, customTabView, deviceLayerInterface);
    TabCustomViewFunctions.createNewFile(this, customTabView, deviceLayerInterface);
    TabCustomViewFunctions.saveFile(customTabView, deviceLayerInterface);

    /* Set up pages and device info */
    deviceInfo = deviceLayerInterface.getDeviceInfo();
    pages = deviceLayerInterface.getPages();
    setUpPages(pages);

    /* Action Bar */
    actionBarTabs = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBarTabs.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBarTabs.setCustomView(customTabView);
    actionBarTabs.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);    

    /* Adds fragments to the tabs adapter */
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("FRAG1"), Fragment_1.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("FRAG2"), Fragment_2.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("FRAG3"), Fragment_3.class, null);

}
}
```

Fragment code:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment
{
private View view;
private CustomLayout layout; // Container view layout class instance
private SlidingTabsActivity slidingTabsActivity;
private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
private Page page;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

    /* Creates the new views from the layout class */
    slidingTabsActivity = (SlidingTabsActivity) getSherlockActivity();
    deviceInfo = slidingTabsActivity.getDeviceInfo();
    page = slidingTabsActivity.getPage1(); 

    if(page != null & deviceInfo != null)
    {
        layout = new CustomLayout(slidingTabsActivity);
        layout.setDeviceInfo(deviceInfo);
        layout.setPage(page);
        layout.createView();

        System.out.println("Page and device info are NOT null!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Page and device info are null!");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity CallBacks using Interface . Callbacks are use to Refreshing the fragments.

This link  [Communication With Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) will help you.